# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setOnInsert'

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Using a standalone MongoDB instance in version *4.4.1* with a Java client that connects using the latest driver (`org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.1.1`), I am getting an error when calling `findOneAndUpdate` with the *$setOnInsert* operator.

Here is the query used:

```java
final List<Bson> updates = new ArrayList<>();
updates.add(Updates.set("data", "test"));
updates.add(Updates.setOnInsert("firstSeenTime", new Date()));

final Document updatedDocument =
    this.visitorsCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
        eq("userId", "u1"), updates, new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER).upsert(true));
```

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command
> failed with error 40324 (Location40324): 'Unrecognized pipeline stage
> name: '$setOnInsert'' on server A.B.C.D:XXXXX. The full
> response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Unrecognized pipeline stage name:
> '$setOnInsert'", "code": 40324, "codeName": "Location40324"}  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:359)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:280)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:100)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:490)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:255)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:110)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper$13.call(CommandOperationHelper.java:712)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:620)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:705)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:697)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.BaseFindAndModifyOperation.execute(BaseFindAndModifyOperation.java:69)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:195)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeFindOneAndUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:785)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.findOneAndUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:765)

If I get rid of the `Updates.setOnInsert(...)` call, then the update works but not as I would like. My purpose is to set some fields based on whether the document to update exists or not. Looking at the documentation, *$setOnInsert* should be supported:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1

Any idea about what is wrong?

Comment: I might be mislead but if the error `Unrecognized pipeline stage name` really meant stage name, then `$setOnInsert` doesn't exist as a stage name but `$set` does exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help but if you look at the link (from the official documentation) I put in my problem description you will see that `$setOnInsert` is a valid update operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is there are 2 forms of findOneAndUpdate.  The second argument can be either:

- a document containing update operator expressions
- an array containing `$set`, `$unset`, and `$replaceRoot` aggregation stages

Since you are creating `updates` as an ArrayList, findOneAndUpdate is trying to process it as an aggregation pipeline, which does not recognize a `$setOneInsert` stage.

You need to build `updates` as a Document for the update operators to be recognized. Following your example, you can simply wrap the list with `Updates.combine(updates)` and pass it to `findOneAndUpdate` as the second parameter.